# Strange object value instead of float by using mapReduce in mongodb with Doctrine

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, mapreduce, doctrine

I use mongo query for calculating sum price for every item.
My query looks like so

$queryBuilder = new Query\Builder($this, $documentName);

```
$queryBuilder->field('created')->gte($startDate);
$queryBuilder->field('is_test_value')->notEqual(true);
..........
$queryBuilder->map('function() {emit(this.item, this.price)}');
$queryBuilder->reduce('function(item, valuesPrices) {
    return {sum: Array.sum(valuesPrices)}
}');
```

And this works, no problem. But I found that in some cases (approximately 20 cases from 200 results) I have strange result in field `sum` - instead of sum value I see construction like

`[objectObject]444444444444444`

4 - is price for item.

I tried to replace reduce block to block like this:

```
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < valuesPrices.length; i++) {
        sum += parseFloat(valuesPrices[i]);
    }
    return {sum: sum}
```

In that case I see `NAN` value.

I suspected that some data in field `price` was inserted incorrectly (not as float, but as string, object etc). I tried execute my query from mongo cli and I see that all price values are integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "strange" at all. You [*"broke the rules"*](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) and now you are paying for it.

> - *"MongoDB can invoke the reduce function more than once for the same key. In this case, the previous output from the reduce function for that key will become one of the input values to the next reduce function invocation for that key."*

The primary rule of `mapReduce` (as cited ) is that you **must** return **exactly** the same structure from the "reducer" as you do from the "mapper". This is because the "reducer" can actually run several times for the same "key". This is how `mapReduce` processes large lists.

You fix this by just returning a singular value, just like you did in the emit:

```js
return Array.sum(values);
```

And then there will not be a problem. Adding an object key to that makes the data inconsistent, and thus you get an error when the "reduced" result gets fed back into the "reducer" again.

Comment: Thank you @Blakes Saven. It is my first experience with mapReduce and I made mistake.

Comment: @yAnTar It is actually a "common mistake" as many people miss that as a concept by "assuming" the "reducer" function only ever gets called **once**. And in small data testing, that is in fact the only result they see. Actually for your particular operation you would be better off using the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) instead, but that is maybe another question. Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that solves the problem.